# Performing stop of activity that is already stopped

Tags: android, android-activity

Recently I've seen the error in the logcat "Performing stop of activity that is already stopped" but I am not sure yet this is causing to crash the app yet but I am bit nervous some people might be getting in Production as I am not able to reproduce it at all.

Has anyone comeup with this issue by any chance what could be causing this.

```
10-13 06:15:16.306 15134-15134/food.ready.Debug E/ActivityThread: Performing stop of activity that is already stopped: {food.ready.Debug/food.ready.app.activity.MainActivity}
java.lang.RuntimeException: Performing stop of activity that is already stopped: {food.ready.Debug/food.ready.app.activity.MainActivity}
at android.app.ActivityThread.performStopActivityInner(ActivityThread.java:4052)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStopActivity(ActivityThread.java:4140)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap24(Unknown Source:0)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1627)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
10-13 06:15:16.307 15134-15134/food.ready.Debug E/ActivityThread: ActivityClientRecord{paused=true, stopped=true, hideForNow=false, startsNotResumed=false, isForward=true, pendingConfigChanges=0, onlyLocalRequest=false, preserveWindow=false, Activity{resumed=false, stopped=true, finished=false, destroyed=false, startedActivity=false, temporaryPause=false, changingConfigurations=false, visibleBehind=false}}
```

Comment: I just started getting this exception too and I am able to reproduce it reliably. It happens every time I open an interstitial behind a locked screen. I open the interstitial from an activity that is showing over the lock screen and because the interstitial doesn't have the flags to show on the lock screen, the screen locks and I get the exception. It doesn't seem to crash my app either. This may not be the actual cause, this is just the sequence of events that result in the exception. Also when the same sequence of events occurs on an unlocked screen I get no exception.

Comment: @spaceman I have encountered the same issue on Android versions >= 8.1.1. I can't figure out whats wrong with it coz on lower Android versions it works as expected. To avoid this exception I'm requesting keyguard dismissing by a user and show my activity after that on Android >= 8.1.1. If you know a solution for that bug could you please post it here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52299463/android-8-1-0-activity-is-stopped-when-was-started-on-locked-screen ?